# How can I fix error of broadcasting state and emission probability using hidden_markov?

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models

I am having problem with hidden_markov package when applying a slight change in a simple example in its documentation. In the following code I try 2 states and 3 possible observations (in the documentation's example there are 2 possible observations and the code works fine):

```
states = ('s', 't')
possible_observation = ('A', 'B', 'C')

# Numpy arrays of the data

start_probability = np.matrix( '0.5 0.5')
transition_probability = np.matrix('0.6 0.4 ; 0.3 0.7')
emission_probability = np.matrix( '0.3 0.2 0.5 ; 0.3 0.1 0.6')

# Initialize class object

test = hmm(states,possible_observation,
           start_probability,
           transition_probability,
           emission_probability)

observations = ('A', 'B','B','A', 'C')
obs4 = ('B', 'C', 'A','B')
observation_tuple = []
observation_tuple.extend( [observations,obs4] )
quantities_observations = [18, 28]
num_iter=1000

e,t,s = test.train_hmm(observation_tuple,num_iter,quantities_observations)
```

After running the code I get the error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (1,2)
```

Interestingly, when I try 3 states and 3 possible observations (and modify the probability matrices based on this change) the code works fine. Either I am missing something, or the number of states and possible observations should always be equal which does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the matrix you have provided above, there are only two matrices that have the shape `(2,3)` and `(1,2)` which are `emission_probability` and `start_probability` respectively and the error is of the matrix dimension mismatch. To match the matrix dimensions so that they can be used for calculation of dot product is by doing.

```
emission_probability = emission_probability.T
start_probability = start_probability.T
```

This step has to be done before initializing the class object.

Comment: I added this but I get ValueError: Emission probability has incorrect dimensions. I should also add I mistakenly said in the title that I am using hmmlearn. I am in fact using hidden_markov (https://pypi.org/project/hidden_markov/) package. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Sina I haven't worked with Hidden Markov, neither have I worked with the library you have linked. I will look into it and get back, but it will take some time.